# Dog pees too much problem

Tags: dogs

Ever since last week my dog (7 year old golden retriever) has been peeing at an unusual amount and licking her anus just as much. Also, a white substance appears in her urine. This all started after i showered her about a week ago and i dont know what is going on

Comment: I think the vet should answer this question..

Comment: The white substance is the pus. It's very likely an inflammation or infection... Looking up "white substance in dog urine" will present you a lot of information about why your dog could be going through this. Regardless, please see the vet.

Answer (score 2):

She probably has a UTI (urinary tract infection). I would see a vet to get it properly diagnosed and treated.

Comment: I concur from OP it is a UTI which requires an antibiotic. If not treated, may create a life-threatening infection. Please see a veterinarian IMMEDIATELY.